# Lookup Relationship question

Tags: force.com, relationships

I'm still new-ish to SF, so sorry  if this is a stupid question.

**Set-up**

I create an object, test, and at creation I allow activities to be associated with that object.  Test has a lookup relationship with activities via the related to field.  Say I create a record for test and an activity related to it.

**Question:**
when I delete the test object record, why is the activity record deleted? according to SF look-up relationships have "no effect on deletion or security."

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm

Help!

Das Noobre

(Not sure which tag to use here for general SF questions, so sorry in advance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relationship fields on Activity aren't actually Lookups, but [polymorphic relationship](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#i1422356) fields. This is a special field type that the platform uses when a child record can have a relationship to more than one type of Parent. They aren't available as a field type to Salesforce users when defining new relationships in the database but they do show up on a few Standard objects.

They behave more like Master/Detail relationship fields when it comes to parent deletion.

Comment: Ah, I was going off the 'Schema builder' tool w to see the relationship. Now I understand his wasn't behaving like a look up!  Sooo who's the "parent" of this activity? is it the whoId (contact/lead) or the Whatid (test)? If I delete teh record referenced by either the who/what Id does the activity get deleted? ... Thanks Kevin

Comment: Yes, the WhoId is always either a Contact or a Lead. The WhatId can pretty much be anything else. In your case, the WhatId would be your Test object.

Comment: +1, Standard objects often have unique functionality that isn't available to custom objects. It's always worth reading the API docs (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)

Comment: SO an activity has 2 parents: the WhoId and the WhatId- right?. When you delete either parent, the activity is deleted. Can someone explain why?